# Unable to access Jenkins container outside of host network

Tags: jenkins, containers

I am stuck in a step. I am using an ubuntu vm which is in Azure cloud through terminal; don't have UI access. There I have installed docker and pulled the jenkins image. I have mapped this container from my host machine by running following command - docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins to access this jenkins from my MAC using Ubuntu IP address:8080, however I am getting the This site cannot be reached. So do I am following or missed any steps to mapped the container outside of docker host machine? Please help!

Comment: add few more details on what procedures you were following and from where, this will help others to understand your query easily.

Comment: Hi Vicky, My requirement was simple to create Jenkins container on Azure VM (Docker Host Machine). Now I am want to access this Jenkins setup from my local machine. I am accessing this host machine through ssh and dont have UI access.